# python3.5 instruction not allowed statsmodels

Tags: ubuntu, debian, python-3.5, statsmodels

When I use :

```
res=model.fit()
```

on my ubutu serve with debian9 using python3.5 it close python print

```
instruction not allowed
```

It's the first time i see it whereas it not the first time i use `model.fit()`.

Does anyone know how to solve this please?

I see nothing on the web to solve this. Maybe it's links with right of files it will explain why this error is not always here.

thanks a lot =)

Comment: The *model* and *fit()* could be anything. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). P.S. How can you have ubuntu server _with_ debian 9?

Comment: sorry it is just debian9.

Comment: here is an exemple (i dont manage to modify my own post )

import statsmodels.api as sm
vy= [[1.],[1.], [1.]]
vx=[[1000.], [8280.], [9000.]]
X = sm.add_constant(vx)
model = sm.OLS(vy,X)
results = model.fit()  

when i use that on jupyter all is okay 
but on my server that crash.

Comment: Aftet some research   it seems that could be ling to buch of instructions use by the CPU.

I don't know how to this the CPU bunch instruction use in statsmodels, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that is numpy SVD whtch is the cause of that, to solve that i will move from debian9 to ubuntu.